# Does the latest version of Safari automatically refresh a page when returning to a tab?

Tags: safari

Since I got the latest update of Safari there seems to be a change in behavior. If I have several tabs open and I return to a tab after being on another one for a while, it refreshes the page. The same thing happens after returning to Safari from another application. Where this is problematic is when I have a url for a script in a tab, it runs the script again. So,

1. Am I crazy, is it really deciding on its own to refresh after a certain period of absence from the tab?
2. Can I turn this behavior off?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a feature (or any bug that has been mentioned that I can find). If you some reason you want to cause this behavior, you have use [this](http://hailstonesoftware.com/articles/2004/09/09/auto-refresh-safari-page). It could be that you have scripts running on the page that are causing the refresh (nytimes.com for example refreshes every once in a while).

Comment: While some pages do self-refresh periodically as you noted, these are not the pages I am concerned with. I did find that URLs that run scripts do not run again, even though the page goes blank and refreshes. It is this going blank and redisplaying the page that is a new behavior.